# user.presence.status is now working in discord.js v13

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I wanted my bot to set the name of a channel: the number of users. I wanted to filter online/dnd/idle members and offline members. but my code is not working.

**My code:**

```js
let humanMembers = guild.members.cache.filter(
  (user) => !user.user.bot
);
let onlineMembers = guild.members.cache.filter(
  (member) => !member.user.bot && member.user.presence.status !== "offline"
)
const channel = guild.channels.cache.get('863783336860975114');
channel.setName(` Online: ${onlineMembers.size.toString()}/${humanMembers.size.toString()}`);
```

**The error:**

```
cannot read properties of undefined <reading 'status'>
at main.js:37:65
```

I am using discord.js v13 and node.js v16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`User.presence` has been removed in v13](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#user)

You can use [`GuildMember.presence`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/v13/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=presence) if you have `GUILD_PRESENCES` intent enabled.

Instead of using `member.user.presence` use `member.presence`

Comment: It sets the name of the channel to ` Online:103/103`

Comment: @Pooyan as I mentioned in my answer, you must enable `GUILD_PRESENCES` intent, otherwise `GuildMember.presence` will be null. https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#guildmember

Comment: Yeah, I know. It is enabled.

Comment: Oh, could you try to print out what `member.presence.status` is?

Comment: when I use `let onlineMembers = guild.members.cache.filter((member) => !member.user.bot && member.presence?.status == 'online' && member.presence?.status == 'idle' && member.presence?.status == 'dnd');` it set the name of channel: **0/103**. but when I use `let onlineMembers = guild.members.cache.filter((member) => !member.user.bot && member.presence?.status == 'online');`. it works correctly: **11/103**

Comment: You're checking whether the status is 'online' AND 'idle' AND 'dnd', Instead of using `&&` (AND) you should use `||` (OR)

Comment: Btw. instead of filtering `guild.members.cache` you can just use `humanMembers.filter` and remove the bot detection, as it is being used in both filters